# Return group_id after using group_create function

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I use phpBB's function `group_create()` to add a new group to my forum :

```
//CREATION GROUPE HUB
                    $group_id = '';
                    $group_type = 0;
                    $group_name = "Hub ".$IATA;
                    $group_desc = "Groupe du HUB de ".$nom.". Pour intégrer ce hub, veuillez faire une demande auprès des chefs de HUB.";

                    $group_attributes = array(
                        'group_colour' => '00FFFF',
                        'group_rank' => 0, 
                        'group_avatar' => 0, 
                        'group_avatar_type' => 0,
                        'group_avatar_width' => 0,
                        'group_avatar_height' => 0,
                        'group_legend' => 0,
                        'group_receive_pm' => 1,
                    );           
                    $group = group_create($group_id, $group_type, $group_name, $group_desc, $group_attributes);
```

But I can't get the group_id which has been created. I've tried with `$group` but the return of this variable is : `bool(false)`
I precise that the function works, the group is created.

Comment: What's the value of `$group_id` after calling `group_create()`?

Comment: The id of the group which has been created.

Comment: Is that not what you need, then?

Comment: Oh sorry, the var `$group_id`has no value after calling `group_create()` and `$group`doesn't return the id that I want.

Answer (score 0):

phpBB still has some weird functions for example `strip_bbcode()` or `group_create()` which aren't working like we would expect.

Well.. they do but the return values aren't as expected as you may have noticed. ;)

The function returns only an error, if some occured, or `false`. The group id will be in the parameter `$group_id` after the call since the variable is given by reference.